# Jedi USB project read and write Delphi

Tags: delphi, usb, hid, jedi

I am using the Jedi usb hid component to connect to, read and write from a HID device. I have been unable to write to the device. I have been using this code.

```
type
TReport = Packed record
 ReportID: byte;
 Data: array [0..64] of byte;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 I:integer;
 HidData:TReport;
 written:DWORD;
begin
hiddata.ReportID:=0;
hiddata.Data[0]:=0;
hiddata.Data[1]:=$80;
  for I := 2 to 64 do
    hiddata.Data[I]:=$FF;
currentdevice.WriteFile(hiddata,currentdevice.Caps.OutputReportByteLength,written);
end;
```

Comment: You need to provide much more information.  How do you know you're not writing?  What happens?  Is there an error message, an exception, a value for GetLastError()?  I see someone is down voting you without explaining why, which isn't very friendly of them, but this will be the reason why - as it stands, this question doesn't have enough information to be answered.

Comment: Well ondevicedata, I put in label7.Caption:= hiddev.ProductName+' - '+floattostr(size) so i could check to make sure it was the right device, when I run it the label only says "65", as well as he device does not receive the command, I know this because the device works with other programs.

Answer (score 6):

I made a test platform which you can use :

```
unit BasicMain; 

interface 

uses 
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, StdCtrls, Forms, Dialogs,
JvHidControllerClass, JvComponentBase; 

type 

TReport = packed record 
  ReportID: byte; 
  Data: array [0..64] of byte; 
end; 

TMainForm = class(TForm) 
  HidCtl: TJvHidDeviceController; 
  DeviceList: TListBox; 
  Label1: TLabel; 
  Label2: TLabel; 
  Button1: TButton; 
  procedure HidCtlDeviceChange(Sender: TObject); 
  function HidCtlEnumerate(HidDev: TJvHidDevice;const Idx: Integer): Boolean; 
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
  procedure FormCreate( Sender : TObject);
  procedure DeviceRemoval(HidDev: TJvHidDevice); 
  procedure DeviceArrival(HidDev: TJvHidDevice); 
  public 
end; 

var 
  MainForm: TMainForm; 
  MyDevice: TJvHidDevice; 

implementation 

{$R *.dfm} 
{ ***************************************************************************** } 

Const 
  MyVendorID = $04D8;   // Put in your matching VendorID
  MyProductID = $003F;  // Put in your matching ProductID

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate( Sender : TObject);
begin
  HidCtl.OnArrival:= DeviceArrival; 
  HidCtl.OnRemoval:= DeviceRemoval; 
end;

procedure TMainForm.DeviceRemoval(HidDev: TJvHidDevice); 
begin 
  if ((Assigned(MyDevice)) and (NOT MyDevice.IsPluggedIn)) then 
  begin 
    HidCtl.CheckIn(MyDevice); 
  end; 
end; 

procedure TMainForm.DeviceArrival(HidDev: TJvHidDevice); 
begin 
  if ((HidDev.Attributes.VendorID = MyVendorID) AND 
     (HidDev.Attributes.ProductID = MyProductID) AND 
     (HidDev.Caps.OutputReportByteLength = SizeOf(TReport)) ) then 
  begin 
    if HidDev.CheckOut then 
    begin 
      MyDevice := HidDev; 
    end; 
  end; 
end; 

procedure TMainForm.HidCtlDeviceChange(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Label1.Caption := '-'; 
  Label2.Caption := '-'; 
  MyDevice := nil; 
  DeviceList.Clear; 
  HidCtl.Enumerate; 
end; 

function TMainForm.HidCtlEnumerate(HidDev: TJvHidDevice;const Idx: Integer): Boolean; 
begin 
  DeviceList.Items.Add( 
  Format('%.4x/%.4x', [HidDev.Attributes.VendorID,HidDev.Attributes.ProductID])); 
  if (HidDev.Attributes.VendorID = MyVendorID) and (HidDev.Attributes.ProductID =         MyProductID) then 
  begin 
    HidCtl.CheckOut(HidDev);
    MyDevice := HidDev; 
    Label1.Caption := Format('%.4x/%.4x', [MyDevice.Attributes.VendorID ,   MyDevice.Attributes.ProductID]); 
    Label2.Caption := 'Length = '+ IntToStr(MyDevice.Caps.OutputReportByteLength) + ' ' + IntToStr(MyDevice.Caps.InputReportByteLength); 
  end; 
  Result := True; 
end; 

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  HidData : TReport; 
  written : DWORD; 
begin 
  HidData.ReportID:=0; 
  HidData.Data[0]:=$80;
  // Fill with more data 

  MyDevice.WriteFile(HidData, MyDevice.Caps.OutputReportByteLength, Written); 
  MyDevice.ReadFile(HidData, MyDevice.Caps.InputReportByteLength, Written); 
end; 

end.
```

> 

```
object MainForm: TMainForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'MainForm'
  ClientHeight = 341
  ClientWidth = 535
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 48
    Top = 8
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 48
    Top = 27
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label2'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 48
    Top = 46
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    Left = 48
    Top = 96
    Width = 465
    Height = 97
    ItemHeight = 13
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Fill in your VendorID and ProductID and the output data.

Comment: Thanks, But the readfile command make the program freeze, and its still not reaching the device.

Comment: Remove the ReadFile line. Add an OnDeviceData method and output size to some text label. Please tell us more about the device and state output data size and input data size.

Comment: label3.Caption:= hiddev.ProductName+' - '+Floattostr(size); I put this line in OnDeviceData and the labels caption does not change. My device is a 18F2550 that on receiving a command switches a relay on or off. I have a working VC++ demo, here is the link. [link](http://downloads.meeser.co.za/demo.zip)

Comment: What is the reported size of MyDevice.Caps.OutputReportByteLength and MyDevice.Caps.InputReportByteLength ?

Comment: Ok, then I'm out of plausible explanations. Do you have a USB protocol analyzer to monitor the traffic ? There are software doing this, like [usb-monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/usb-monitor).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting usb-monitor, While using it, I Noticed It was sending data to the device, but it but the queue needed to be flushed before the data would send properly.

Answer (score 3):

Effictivly one line do the trick that the writefile method is accepted or not :

```
ToWrite := TheDev.Caps.OutputReportByteLength;
TheDev.WriteFile(buffer,towrite,written);
```

The device accept only write of the correct buffer length. It doesn't work if you write only a part of the buffer length.