# Reading a barcode from a scanner into a variable in a Delphi program

Tags: delphi, usb, barcode

I'm currently creating a program using delphi for a college project, the project involves scanning books in and out of a library, I was going to use a USB Barcode Scanner to read the barcodes but was wondering how I get the digits read from the scanner into a variable in Delphi?
Thanks, George.

Comment: There's [`a few questions`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+barcode+scanner) asked here and Google will also surely help unless you tell us more about scanner model you're going to use.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all USB barcode scanners emulate the keyboard and stuff the characters into the keyboard buffer. You shouldn't need to do anything. Simply have an edit control on a form, give it focus, scan your barcode, read the value of the edit, clear it, reset focus then rinse and repeat. Of course, you will have the issue of discerning the difference between regular keyboard input and the scanner, but that's another issue.

Comment: So they could just select an edit box the the barcode and scan it in?
Is there a way I could get it to read it straight into a variable without the need for an edit box? So they don't see the numbers being entered?

Comment: You should be able to hook the keypress event of the form, but you'd then need to differentiate between input from the barcode reader and regular keyboard input from the user. How you do this depends on the nature of your application and what the users expect. A crude approach would be to measure the time between individual key presses.

Comment: That could work, what other methods are there to differentiate between them?
Could I somehow see what USB port the information is being read from?

Comment: Potentially you could, but you'd need to do quite a bit of quite low-level USB programming which is probably beyond the scope of your project. The scanner manufacturer may provide an API to allow you to read the input discretely, but these are rare IME. In the old days it was easier as you could get RS-232 ones and you knew exactly where the input was coming from as you effectively had a dedicated port for the device.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely beyond the scope of the project :L
Thanks for all the advice, for now I'll use an edit box and change it later on when I'm ironing out any bugs/problems.

Comment: You ***cannot*** distinguish between input form the keyboard and from the USB bar-code reader. When expecting input, prompt, flush the keyboard  input and hook the keyboard. When you have read the barcode (check the input string length), clear the hook

Answer (score 1):

I use the TJvHidDeviceController to directly read barcode data from an usb scanner, for example: 
[Jedi USB project read and write Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258075/jedi-usb-project-read-and-write-delphi/8260122#8260122)

This is much better than having the scanner in wedge mode because then you need to keep the focus in an editbox all the time